# Views are not redrawing after the new width and height are set

Tags: android

I am killing myself with this problem so I am in desperate need of help.

I have a fragment with custom layout which is populated programmatically with linear layout which consists of an imageview and a textview.

User can dynamically change size of the fragment and here lies the problem.

I have onLayoutChange listener set on the fragment view where i change the size of the textview in respect to the size of the container and everything is correctly set when the container size changes but the views don't redraw themself and after the change all that i can see are the old views with their old width and height as if new width and height have never been applied.

I tried to invalidate the textview and i tried to call requestlayout on the parent view to no avail.

Its as if the new views are set but the old ones are shown.

Heres the code:

```
private void GenerateViews(View view) {

    for (final Item artikl : listaArtikala) {

        LinearLayout l_artikl = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        l_artikl.setPadding(10, 5, 0, 5);

        final ImageView img = new ImageView(getActivity());         
        img.setMinimumWidth(image_width);
        img.setMinimumHeight(image_height);
        img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        l_artikl.addView(img);

        final TextView txv = new TextView(getActivity());

    // dummy if to trigger after container size changes.        
        if(txv_artikl_width > 265)
            txv.setWidth(300);
        else
            txv.setWidth(100);

        txv.setWidth(300);              
        txv.setHeight(txv_artikl_height);
        txv.setText(artikl.getName());
        txv.setTextSize(15);
        txv.setClickable(true);

        txv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        txv.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
                R.color.LightSteelBlue));
        txv.setPadding(5, 0, 10, 5);            

        l_artikl.addView(txv);

        ((ViewGroup) view).addView(l_artikl);
    }


    view.requestLayout();
}
```

All the help is appreciated.

Comment: I have another problem. When i remove all the child views from the layout and then generate new ones none of them are shown..the layout is blank. I tried invalidate(), requestLayout().

Answer (score 0):

After your if statement you reset the width of your textview:

```
  if(txv_artikl_width > 265)
        txv.setWidth(300);
    else
        txv.setWidth(100);

    txv.setWidth(300);
```

You probably don't want to do that, right?

Comment: I'm not using ActionBar Tabs. I am using custom layout which i populate with view's for example if i populate it with textview's and after that in runtime i change the size of textviews i wont see their new size..what i will see is their old size as if nothing changed

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to give this answer for another question. I'll edit my answer in a bit.

Comment: Ohh i didn't see that but even without it its still the same. The new width is set but the textview isn't redrawn with the new parameters :)